# Sun Grid Engine huhohshdhjha

Tags: command-line-interface, gridengine

when I type `qstat -h`, I get the following option

```
   [-s {p|r|s|z|hu|ho|hs|hd|hj|ha|h|a}] show pending, running, suspended, zombie jobs,
                                      jobs with a user/operator/system/array-dependency hold, 
                                      jobs with a start time in future or any combination only.
                                      h is an abbreviation for huhohshdhjha
                                      a is an abbreviation for prsh
```

What in the world is `huhohshdhjha`????

Comment: Best relevant gibberish question title ever!

Comment: I nearly thought it was spam.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[From the `man` page](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/qstat/):

> -s {p|r|s|z|hu|ho|hs|hd|hj|ha|h|a}[+]
>
> Prints only jobs in the specified state, **any combination of states is possible**. -s prs corresponds to the regular qstat output without -s at all. To show recently finished jobs, use -s z. To display jobs in user/operator/system/array-dependency hold, use the -s hu/ho/hs/hd option. The -s ha option shows jobs which where submitted with the qsub -a command. qstat -s hj displays all jobs which are not eligible for execution unless the job has entries in the job dependency list. **qstat -s h is an abbreviation for qstat -s huhohshdhjha** and qstat -s a is an abbreviation for qstat -s psr (see -a, -hold_jid and -hold_jid_ad options to

Emphasis added.

It's a combination of the `hu`, `ho`, `hs`, `hd`, `hj` and `ha` states, and is abbreviated as `qstat -s h`, which seems much perferable to typing all those options out.  **In practical terms, it's the option to print all the jobs that are on hold.**  `hu` == user hold, `ho` == operator hold, `hs` == system hold, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I assume `huhohshdhjha` is the combination of the options `hu`, `ho`, `hs`, `hd`, `hj`, and `ha`, as this is a general way of combining command line options.

A random other example:

```
netstat -ntlp
```

Then one can ask likewise: "what the heck is the `ntlp` option? It's not in the manpage!"